# Stereo camera calibration fundamental matrix

Tags: calibration, stereo, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing a stereo camera driver, and am using the camera_calibrate package, with the command:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --approximate=0.1 --size 9x6 --square 0.025 right:=/stereocamera/right/image_raw left:=/stereocamera/left/image_raw left_camera:=/stereocamera/left right_camera:=/stereocamera/right
```

When storing the results to the camera this seems to trigger *set_camera_info* for the left and right cameras, but what about the mapping between the two cameras (the fundamental matrix calculation)?  Does *camera_calibration* do this, and if so what service call does it use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29050/stereo-camera-calibration-fundamental-matrix/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2012-03-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using the camera_calibration package for stereo camera calibration the images of right and left camera are rectified and adjusted to become "ideal" stereo images. That means that corresponding points in left and right image have the same value in `y` (i.e. the epipoles are infinite, epipolar lines are parallel to the x-axis).

In this setting, no fundamental matrix but the baseline (distance from left to right camera center) is needed for 3D triangulation. This information is found in the [CameraInfo](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) message of the right camera. Please have a look at the [CameraInfo](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) message and at corresponding [documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_pipeline/CameraInfo).

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3